# What is an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

What exactly is an algorithm, as in what does Algorithm mean? The little I understand the word, is that it's not specific to a particular language, or design pattern, rather it's one the most basic principles (so I guess this question makes me look stupid).

One of the "options" I have of understanding it, is that it means the method of getting something done, that could be written as a list in pseudocode.

When I write more complicated code, I think what needs to be done, with what, and how I would get there (not in a programming language), then write that in code. Is that good way to go about it, and is that anything to do with algorithms?

(I wanted to ask here rather on Stackoverflow, because it's not about a specific problem/language plus I get the feeling that the majority of people here know the 'why', or at least the answers here are more detailed, rather than on Stackoverflow where it's different, I'm sorry if I should have asked over there)

Comment: Google? Wiki? http://www.google.com/search?q=algorithm

Comment: Not quite as useful, or easy to understand as here. Wikipedia wasn't that useful to me at least.

Comment: An algorithm is the description of thhe set of steps to take to solve a problem within **known and limited resources and  time**.  Anything else is a _procedure_ or maybe an _heuristic_.

Comment: @Apalala: I don't think those limitations apply.

Comment: I must be getting old.  This used to be one of the standard definitions given in the first week of *ANY* programming 101 class, no matter which department (math, EE, CS, ME, physics, CE, ChE, the business school, ...) taught the class.

Comment: "Wikipedia wasn't that useful to me at least".  Either that's a lie or it's an incomplete statement.  Please **update** the question to identify something **specific** that confuses you.

Comment: @Josh The Wikipedia definition is fine. The keyword is _finite_.

Comment: @Apalala: *Finite*, not *known*.

Comment: What I mean is Wikipedia uses words that I have to look up and I end up in a catch 22 loop. Besides this site means I can talk back and get more than one definition written in a slightly different way.

Comment: @Jonathan: "words that I have to look up"?  Which words?  Be **specific**.  This site is not magic.  We don't know you.  We don't know what you read.  We don't know what confused you.  Please be **specific**.

Comment: My point was that the Wikipedia article on algorithms references other articles which use references to other articles, etc which eventually leads back to algorithm. I just needed a starting point which is why I asked this question. Then I can go back to Wikipedia and the rest of the Internet and understand the rest myself

Comment: @John _Finite_ means _predictable_, and thus _known_. It's mathematical. Describe the algorithm, describe the computer, and describe the problem set, and the running time and resources can be bounded with 100% accuracy, which is as good as _known_ gets. Algorithms make _Big O_ possible. On the other hand, if it's not an **algorithm**, then, yeah, you _don't know_.

Comment: @Apalala:  "Finite" means "bounded", nothing more.  An algorithm is guaranteed to stop sometime.  It's much easier to prove finiteness when you have some sort of way of predicting it will end, so algorithms tend to be predictable, but predictability is not in the usual definition of algorithms.

Comment: @David What distinguishes simple procedures and heuristics from algorithms? I'm fine with exchanging _bounded_ for _finite_, and dropping _known_. I won't drop _predictable as bounded_, as that would do away with all of engineering. An `O(A * log B*N)` is just `O(log N)` in mathematics, but a quite good prediction in engineering if `A` `B` are estimated accurately.

Answer (score 19):

An algorithm is a finite sequence of well-defined instructions for calculating a function (or executing a procedure) that terminates in a well-defined ending state.

Comment: +1.  "Finite, Well-Defined and Effective" are the three criteria in the Wikipedia entry.  You have all three here, also.

Comment: I'm set up to watch the videos quoted by @Jörg, but my current point of view is that not only the steps must be finite. If the resources (including time) are not bounded, then the procedure can be called or labeled as anything, but not an _algorithm_.

Comment: @Apalala - I've been going back through my textbooks, and I don't see that restriction anywhere.  It's possible that for a *particular* data set or input an algorithm may not terminate (algorithms like the Newton-Raphson method for finding a root may get stuck in a never-ending loop), but that doesn't make the algorithm not an algorithm.

Comment: @John Oscillations can and routinely detected in Newton-Raphson.

Comment: @John This is the definition of **algorithm** in this 1983 book: http://goo.gl/uwNr2. _...is a finite sequence of instructions, each of which has a clear meaning and can be performed with a finite amount of effort in a finite length of time._.

Comment: @Apalala: that sounds more like the definition of a *program* than of an algorithm. This idea of discrete *steps* is present in Turing machines, register machines, random-access machines, and of course in our actual physical computers, also in pretty much every programming language and even, albeit more implicitly, in lambda calculus. But that is an arbitrary restriction that is *not* inherent in algorithms. *Analog* algorithms, for example, do *not* have discrete steps (in fact, that is the *definition* of an analog algorithm), and they *can* actually be implemented with an analog computer.

Comment: According to Knuth you can also add input/output. But then input is defined as having zero or more inputs.

Answer (score 15):

This is actually a pretty interesting question, and in fact still an open research question.

Yuri Gurevich, one of the giants of Algorithm Theory, is currently giving a video lecture series on Microsoft's community website Channel9:

- [C9 Lectures: Yuri Gurevich - Introduction to Algorithms and Computational Complexity, 1 of 3: Introduction and Some History](http://Channel9.MSDN.Com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Algorithms-with-Yuri-Gurevich-Introduction-and-Some-History/)
- [C9 Lectures: Yuri Gurevich - Introduction to Algorithms and Computational Complexity, 2 of 3: What Is An Algorithm?](http://Channel9.MSDN.Com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Yuri-Gurevich-Introduction-to-Algorithms-and-Computational-Complexity-2-of-n/)
- [C9 Lectures: Yuri Gurevich - Introduction to Algorithms and Computational Complexity, 3 of 3](http://Channel9.MSDN.Com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Yuri-Gurevich-Introduction-to-Algorithms-and-Computational-Complexity-3-of-3/)

As you can see, your very question is actually the title of the second lecture. However, I would strongly suggest you watch all three of them.

The first one, in particular, contains a couple of examples of algorithms that invalidate pretty much all of the definitions given in most of the other answers here.

Comment: Thanks for the links. You'll notice the following in the text that accompanies the first video, as a part of the definition of an algorithm: "eventually terminating in a final ending state".  Termination is an essential part of the definition of an algorithm.  That's why operating systems and non-terminating servers are not algorithms.

Comment: @LIProf: Unfortunately, the marketing blurb does not really do the series justice. In fact, literally the very first example given in the very first video, less than 3 minutes in, is of an algorithm that does not always terminate: the geometric interpretation of Euclid's Algorithm, i.e. the way that Euclid originally formulated it, finds the longest common measure of two line segments, but *only if* the two lines segments are commeasurable (IOW, only if there exists a common measure at all).

Comment: And about 16 minutes into the second lecture, Gurevich lists a couple of examples of algorithms, and explicitly lists an Operating System as an example of an algorithm. Another pretty famous algorithm that does not always terminate, is Dijkstra's Algorithm for finding the shortest path in a graph, which may give a wrong answer if there are edges with negative weight, and will not terminate at all if there are cycles with negative weight (because you can always make the path shorter by going round the cycle an additional time).

Answer (score 4):

*An algorithm is like a good cooking recipe*. You have some inputs, some well-defined intermediate steps and get a final result.

Applied to programming, it's an unambiguous description of the steps you need to do solve a particular problem. Anything that you can write down in the programming language of your choice could be seen as an algorithm - but typically the term is only used for common logical or mathematical tasks, such as sorting or searching.

Comment: There are plenty of algorithms that don't necessarily give a final result. An operating system or a web server, for example, is an algorithm for which giving a final result is usually considered a bug.

Comment: @JörgWMittag but is an OS or a web server "an algorithm"? I think they aren't -- they may solve subproblems of their domain using algorithms -- and in every case, they definitely need a final result -- but they also have parts that aren't algorithms, and as a whole they aren't algorithms. (It's like you said in another comment -- OSes and web servers are *programs* but not necessarily *algorithms*).

Answer (score 2):

An algorithm is a set of rules or process (in a calculation) used for problem-solving. Basically, there's a problem, you want a solution, and the process to this solution is an algorithm. An algorithm has a finite sets of rules/process to reach to a solution.

If you're like [Edsger W. Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra), you will write your algorithm on a piece of paper and work out/refine the algorithm on paper till you're satisfied about your algorithms. 
Otherwise (especially when writing documentations), a [flowchart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_chart) is used to diagrammatically represent the flow of an algorithm/process. This allows for others to critique the flowchart and improve if need be (without worrying about what programming language is needed).

I don't know if that answers your question.

Comment: I don't like the word set because it means "not ordered". I'd prefer "sequence", or event tuple to stay in math area

Comment: @Ubiquité, Set doesn't necessarily mean "not ordered". You can classify a set in the ordering you want (e.g. a random ordering). Still, that doesn't require a downvote because of people's interpretation of the word "set". Plus, you can have a compound set, which is a grouping of sets, which also is part of the algorithms. Hence "set" can be anything, as long as its appropriately used as an algorithmic solution to a problem.

Comment: I didn't downvote !

Comment: Sorry, I didn't meant to blame you on the downvote. The downvoter should explicitly provide reasons for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm: a well-ordered set of operations that are 1) unambiguous and 2) effectively computable such that executing the operations starting from the first produces a result after a finite number of operations.

Comment: Counter example: an operating system. It doesn't produce a result *at all*, in fact, that is usually considered a bug.

Comment: @Jörg, well the OS produces many results that, taken together, produce the overall result of providing system services to applications.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Like I said in other comments to you, a conclusion to your observation would be that an operating system is not, in fact, an algorithm ;)

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm
It is the combination of sequential steps (these steps can be calculations, data processing, and reasoning tasks) use to resolve a problem in a very simple and efficient way.

It is designed most efficiently that it can be expressed within a finite amount of space and time. we can implement it in any programming language.

Properties of an algorithm :
following are the main properties of an algorithm:-

An algorithm must have a unique name.
It should have explicitly defined sets of inputs and outputs.
An algorithm must be in sequential order with unambiguous operations.
It must have some endpoint, i.e., it halts in a finite amount of time.
[click here to learn about Design and Analysis of Algorithm](http://geeksjournal.in/2020/01/20/introduction-to-design-and-analysis-of-algorithm/)

Answer (score 0):

I use the term to describe a formula to solve a specific problem.  The formula does not necessarily need to be written in math or have 1:1 relationship with a method.  In school algorithms and data structures are closely related and can be written as math formulas or proven using proofs.

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm is an abstraction of a computer program, and consists of a set of instructions to achieve some well-defined task in a finite number of steps, though the bound on the step count might be very large and the individual steps might be complex (finite) tasks in their own right. While there are (correct) programs that are overall known-non-algorithmic, they all work by repeating algorithmic pieces in some pattern. (More interesting are the programs whose termination status is not known, but most programmers don't actually deal with such things intentionally; I know I don't!)

Answer (score 0):

IMO nobody quite knows :)  I've seen the term applied only to mathematical calculation functions, to *any* function that takes input and produces output, and to *anything* that takes input and performs some kind of operation on it.

Would you consider any/all of the following to be an algorithm?

1. A function that calculates the interest rate of a loan over a period of 20 years
2. Business logic that checks if all information has been entered on a loan application
3. A `finder` function that queries a database for a Customer object
4. A "helper" function that cleans up and formats data-entry
5. A function that parses an XML file and maps data to business objects
6. A class that takes input and writes them to a text file

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm is a sequence of well-defined steps that produce a result in finite time.

Well-defined step:  That's something you can do, or calculate, that is precisely defined.  Just by reading the step you know what you have to do and how to do it.  Specifically, you can write it in a programming language you know, and be sure the program fragment matches the step exactly.

Sequence:  The steps are executed in an order that is specified.  Steps may be executed more than once depending on the data (loops) or not executed at all depending on the data (if statements).  Parallel algorithms impose only a partial order on the steps, so I'm oversimplifying here.  It would be more correct to describe it as a partially-ordered set than a sequence, but I wanted to keep the words a little simpler.  Besides, it's easily possible to embed a partially-ordered set in a full order.

Result:  An ending state or value.  It doesn't have to be predictable in advance, but it does have to be a definite end satisfying some condition.  This does mean that an operating system is not an algorithm, although it uses a whole lot of them.

Finite:  An algorithm is guaranteed to stop sometime, at least on a machine that can run long enough.  It isn't necessarily guaranteed to stop in a predictable time, and it isn't guaranteed that it would stop before the sun expands and turns red on any existing machine.  This also means an operating system is not an algorithm, as ideally it will run forever.  I've seen the word "procedure" used to describe something that would be an algorithm if we were sure it would stop sometime.  (It is possible to have an algorithm that will stop in an unknown amount of time.  Suppose, say Goldbach's conjecture was proved mathematically false, in a nonconstructive proof, so there was an even number > 2 that wasn't the sum of two primes.  An algorithm that simply tested even numbers would then eventually terminate, although nobody would know when.)

The algorithm is an intentionally abstract sort of thing, so we don't consider questions like "Is it physically possible to execute this before the heat death of the Universe?".  They'd be too hard to answer.  If it relates to computer operations, it's easy to implement it in a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

An Algorithm is an idea, a method, a technique, "smarts" for calculation or execution of a task that is abstract in nature, but as it runs on computers in the real world, we **aspire** for it to use **as little resources as possible**, which are, in the computer world, Time and memory.

Answer (score -1):

If I had to give a general definition, I'd say an algorithm is a formula for solving a computing problem that's more complex than, and ends up being more efficient than, the obvious/brute force solution.

Also, it's important to note that an algorithm is not any specific source code; it's the computation itself.  Among other things, this means that any Turing-complete language can implement any algorithm that any other Turing-complete language can implement.

Comment: I liked this answer a lot, and I think we could take it a bit further and say (though not related to the original question): any algorithm is an optimization of a brute force/tree search solution. Was wondering if it can be proven formally.

Comment: -1 "Algorithm" is a well defined mathematical term.

Comment: @Apalala so what stops you from redefining it for the sake of clarity or, say, better understanding of its essence? Algorithm as a "set of instructions" says almost nothing to me.

Comment: @mojuba I really don't care if the term is going to be redefined, but I think that the traditional definition was useful, because it at least differentiated among ways of approaching problems: An algorithm is _a recipe for solving a problem using finite resources_. Change that definition, and the foreseeable consequence is that we will have to come up with another word that means the same. Darn! All the knowledge gained in the past century about computability and complexity goes away without a sound definition of _algorithm_!

Comment: @Apalala: If the OP had wanted a dictionary definition, he could have gone to dictionary.com.  Instead, he came here, which meant he probably wanted a slightly more in-depth explanation.

Comment: A brute force search is an algorithm.  It isn't generally a pretty algorithm, and isn't generally worth writing up.  I don't see any real usefulness in excluding brute force, and in many cases it's not clear what "better than brute force" actually means.